# Json callback single post by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

I have problem to get single post page from WordPress and show it on a mobile jQuery page.
I need to get the full list of posts; and on click, I need to open a single post.

This is my code to get list of posts:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.mcaps.at/redesign/api/get_posts/?post_type=reference_member",
function posts(data) {

    var output='<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="c">';

    $.each(data.posts, function(key,ref){
        output += '<li class="show-more" >';
        output += '<a href="#blog-post" onclick="showPost(' + ref.id + ')">';
        output += '<h3>' + ref.title + '</h3>';
        output += '<img src=" ' + ref.thumbnail + ' " />';
        output += '</a>';
        output += '</li>';
    });

    output+='</ul>';

    $('#referenzen-content').html(output);

});
```

How to get a single post by ID?
Thanks!

Comment: First refer to API documentation, you will find different ways of accessing resources. I couldn't find documentation, can you post API doc link it will be helpful you to get good answer.

Comment: Here is link only to get all post: http://www.mcaps.at/redesign/api/get_posts/?post_type=reference_member   I need to change this link and call like this:  function showPost(id){

  $.getJSON ('http://www.mcaps.at/api/get_post_id=447/?post_type=reference_member',


     function(data){

      
          var output='';
           output+='<h3>'+data.post.title+'</h3>';
           output+= data.post.content;
           
          $('#referenzen-full').html(output);

     });
}

Comment: In the first place the API should have such kind of endpoint, if you own it create it first. If it is not there then only thing you can do is get all the posts ,iterate through and find the post which has the id you want.